# Using map lambda on a dictionary to print 3 values

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I want to get the title, first name and last name from a nested dictionary with 4 sections using the map lambda function

I have tried:

`fullnames_employees = list(map(lambda x: x["title", "firstname", "lastname"], employees))`

`fullnames_employees = list(map(lambda x: x["title"+"firstname"+"lastname"], employees))`

This is the dictionary of employees

```
    {
        "email": "jonathan2532.calderon@gmail.com",
        "employee_id": 101,
        "firstname": "Jonathan",
        "lastname": "Calderon",
        "title": "Mr",
        "work_phone": "(02) 3691 5845"
    },
    {
        "email": "christopher8710.hansen@gmail.com",
        "employee_id": 102,
        "firstname": "Christopher",
        "lastname": "Hansen",
        "title": "Mr",
        "work_phone": "(02) 5807 8580"
    },
    {
        "email": "isabella4643.dorsey@gmail.com",
        "employee_id": 103,
        "firstname": "Isabella",
        "lastname": "Dorsey",
        "title": "Mrs",
        "work_phone": "(02) 6375 1060"
    },
    {
        "email": "barbara1937.baker@gmail.com",
        "employee_id": 104,
        "firstname": "Barbara",
        "lastname": "Baker",
        "title": "Ms",
        "work_phone": "(03) 5729 4873"
    }
]
```

I expect the results to be

`Mr Jonathan Calderon`
etc

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's difficult to tell what is being asked here, and this question cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. Please provide the context, and/or post code samples of what you have done (i.e.: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your lambda function was right to an extent but the way you get the data from the iterate element is wrong. You can't access the list that way, just get the each element data 1 by one and add them to the string and return it.

input data

```
employees = [
    {
        "email": "jonathan2532.calderon@gmail.com",
        "employee_id": 101,
        "firstname": "Jonathan",
        "lastname": "Calderon",
        "title": "Mr",
        "work_phone": "(02) 3691 5845"
    },
    {
        "email": "christopher8710.hansen@gmail.com",
        "employee_id": 102,
        "firstname": "Christopher",
        "lastname": "Hansen",
        "title": "Mr",
        "work_phone": "(02) 5807 8580"
    },
    {
        "email": "isabella4643.dorsey@gmail.com",
        "employee_id": 103,
        "firstname": "Isabella",
        "lastname": "Dorsey",
        "title": "Mrs",
        "work_phone": "(02) 6375 1060"
    },
    {
        "email": "barbara1937.baker@gmail.com",
        "employee_id": 104,
        "firstname": "Barbara",
        "lastname": "Baker",
        "title": "Ms",
        "work_phone": "(03) 5729 4873"
    }
]
```

code

```
fullnames_employees = list(map(lambda x: '{} {} {}'.format(x["title"],x["firstname"],x["lastname"]), employees))
```

output

```
['Mr Jonathan Calderon',
 'Mr Christopher Hansen',
 'Mrs Isabella Dorsey',
 'Ms Barbara Baker']
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access multiple elements of `dictionaries` like `x["title", "firstname", "lastname"]`; you need to do it once per element.

After extracting the desired elements, you can join them with `' '.join`:

```
def extract(person):
    return ' '.join(person[key] for key in ['title', 'firstname', 'lastname'])

fullnames_employees = [extract(person) for person in employees]
print(fullnames_employees)
```

Output:

```
['Mr Jonathan Calderon', 'Mr Christopher Hansen', 'Mrs Isabella Dorsey', 'Ms Barbara Baker']
```

Answer (score 0):

Except lambda I used simple for loop:

```
for i in employees:
    print(i["title"]+ " " + i["firstname"] + " " + i["lastname"] )
```

result:

```
Mr Jonathan Calderon
Mr Christopher Hansen
Mrs Isabella Dorsey
Ms Barbara Baker
```

or simple list comprehension:

```
 print([i["title"]+ " " + i["firstname"] + " " + i["lastname"] for i in employees])
```

Gives:

```
['Mr Jonathan Calderon', 'Mr Christopher Hansen', 'Mrs Isabella Dorsey', 'Ms Barbara Baker']
```